# Updating QtableWidget pyqt5 when changing SQLite database paths

Tags: sqlite, pyqt5

I am trying to update the QtableWidget data list that connects to SQLite where I use SQAlchemy, I have 2 buttons where each button opens a different database path, I press the first button it loads the data list of the first path, but when I press the second button it does not load the other data list. This is the structure of my project

```
app.py
database.py
data.json (Here is the database route)
studenta.db (Database A)
studentb.db (Database B)
```

These are the commands to install the packages in the virtual environment

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install sqlalchemy
```

This is the code of my application

app.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import json


class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        loadUi("list.ui",self)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Id","Name","Lastname"])
        self.pbDatabaseA.clicked.connect(lambda:self.path_database("studenta.db"))
        self.pbDatabaseB.clicked.connect(lambda:self.path_database("studentb.db"))


    def load_data(self):

        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        import database
        
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=database.engine)
        session = Session()

        

        tablerow=0

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        for student in session.query(database.Student).order_by(database.Student.id):
            
            data = [student.id, student.firstname, student.lastname]
            print(data)

            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.EditRole, data[0])
            
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(item))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[1]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[2]))

            tablerow+=1
    

    def path_database(self, path_database):
        with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data["route_open_database"] = path_database
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
            f.truncate()
        
        self.load_data()

    
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow=MainWindow()
widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedWidth(400)
widget.setFixedHeight(300)
widget.show()


try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

list.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>List SQAlchemy</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbDatabaseA">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Database A</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbDatabaseB">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Database B</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
     <column>
      <property name="text">
       <string>C1</string>
      </property>
     </column>
     <column>
      <property name="text">
       <string>C2</string>
      </property>
     </column>
     <column>
      <property name="text">
       <string>C3</string>
      </property>
     </column>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

json_str = json.dumps(data)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
route_open_database = resp['route_open_database']
print(route_open_database)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(route_open_database), echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
 
########################################################################
class Student(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "student"
 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    firstname = Column(String)
    lastname = Column(String)
    university = Column(String)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, username, firstname, lastname, university):
        """"""
        self.username = username
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.university = university

# create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

data.json

```
{
    "route_open_database": "studenta.db"
}
```

studenta.db

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "student" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "username"  VARCHAR,
    "firstname" VARCHAR,
    "lastname"  VARCHAR,
    "university"    VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
INSERT INTO "student" ("id","username","firstname","lastname","university") VALUES (1,'james','James','Boogie','MIT'),
 (2,'lara','Lara','Miami','UU'),
 (3,'eric','Eric','York','Stanford'),
 (4,'jose','Jose','Yomi','MIT');
COMMIT;
```

studentb.db

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "student" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "username"  VARCHAR,
    "firstname" VARCHAR,
    "lastname"  VARCHAR,
    "university"    VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
INSERT INTO "student" ("id","username","firstname","lastname","university") VALUES (1,'james','James','Boogie','MIT'),
 (2,'jose','Jose','Yomi','MIT');
COMMIT;
```

I have tried in the app.py file in the load_data() method to add self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0), to update the data but I can't get it to load the new data from the other database, I would like to know if there is any way to clear the cache of QTableWidget or what recommendation would you give me?

Comment: Modules are cached once they have been imported, so trying to reload a module is pointless. While it is possible to "reload" a module, doing it for your purpose (loading new data from a database) is wrong. Instead, you should create a function that would eventually load the database from the new data file and return the engine. On an unrelated note, it seems like you're probably following a youtube tutorial for the stacked widget, which is known to provide **a lot** of terrible suggestions. I strongly suggest you to completely disregard it.